# How to use basic BLEU score in Asiya Machine Translation Evaluation toolkit?

Tags: perl, nlp, machine-translation, bleu

Asiya is the machine translation evaluation toolkit to score machine translation outputs (http://asiya.lsi.upc.edu/). It is largely written in Perl.

**How do I use Asiya to perform BLEU metrics?**

I have followed the youtube introduction video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rA5De9Z4uWI

And created a config file (Asiya.config):

```
input=raw
srclang=en
srccase=en
trglang=ja
trgcase=ja

src=corpus.tok/test.tok.en
ref=corpus.tok/hyp.tok.ja
sys=corpus.tok/test.tok.ja

some_metrics= BLEU NIST METEOR-ex Ol
```

My machine translation output file is in `corpus.tok/hyp.tok.ja`, the source file is in `corpus.tok/test.tok.en` and the reference file (correct translation) is at `corpus.tok/test.tok.ja`. They are tokenized plain text files, each line is a sentence.

And when I ran:

```
/home/expert/asiya/bin/Asiya.pl -eval single -g all -metric_set some_metrics Asiya.config
```

I got this error:

```
Smartmatch is experimental at /home/expert/asiya/bin/../lib/IQ/Common.pm line 784.
Smartmatch is experimental at /home/expert/asiya/bin/../lib/IQ/Common.pm line 791.
Smartmatch is experimental at /home/expert/asiya/bin/../lib/IQ/Scoring/ESA.pm line 339.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /home/expert/asiya/bin/../lib/IQ/Config.pm line 251.
[ASIYA] directory </tools> does not exist!
```

The tools directory does exists as a subdirectory in the current directory that I ran the command. **What went wrong? Is there a parameter that I could add for the Asiya tools directory?**

How do I use Asiya to perform BLEU evaluation?

**If I don't use Asiya, how else can I get the BLEU score per sentence and system BLEU scores for my machine translation output?**

(more details on http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/redmine/boards/11/topics/138)

Comment: The messages about smartmatch and use of uninitialized value are just warnings, although the latter occurring in IQ/Config.pm suggests that something may be missing in your config file. Beyond that, it's hard to diagnose without seeing the actual code...I would look at line 251 of IQ/Config.pm and see if the text "does not exist!" occurs nearby. If you can find the relevant section of code but aren't sure how to debug it, feel free to edit a snippet into your question.

Comment: Did you try setting the `ASIYA_HOME` environment variable like the project developer told you to on their [support forum](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/redmine/boards/11/topics/138)?